# Spring boot MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException on runtime

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, rest, exception

I have a rest webservice in springboot. Webservice is deleting photos, reviews and place. Now on debugging, rest service is responding with success but after that it gives shows MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException. Now I know that it is giving error because discounts are added in it. I need to show a message if child exist or not. For that I need to catch this exception but I am not able to catch that. I tried SQLException, DataIntegretyViolationException, but not working.

> Web Service Code:

```
    @GetMapping("deletePlaceById/{placeId}")
    @Transactional
    public RestResponse deletePlaceById(@PathVariable Long placeId) {
        try {
            List<PlacePhotosDto> photoList = placePhotosRepo.findByPlaceDto(new PlaceDto(placeId));
            for (PlacePhotosDto placePhotosDto : photoList) {
                AppUtilities.deleteFile(placePhotosDto.getPhotosUrl(), uploadFileDirectory);
            }
            List<PlacePhotosDto> imageList = placePhotosRepo.findByPlaceDto(new PlaceDto(placeId));
            for (PlacePhotosDto placePhotosDto : imageList) {
                placePhotosRepo.deleteById(placePhotosDto.getPhotosId());
            }   

            List<PlaceReviewDto> reviewList = placeReviewRepo.findByPlaceDto(new PlaceDto(placeId));
            for (PlaceReviewDto placeReviewDto : reviewList) {
                placeReviewRepo.deleteById(placeReviewDto.getReviewId());
            }
            placeRepo.deleteById(placeId);
            response = new RestResponse(AppConstants.RESPONSE_TEXT_SUCCESS, AppConstants.RESPONSE_CODE_SUCESS,
                    AppConstants.RESPONSE_TEXT_SUCCESS, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = new RestResponse(AppConstants.RESPONSE_TEXT_ERROR, AppConstants.RESPONSE_CODE_SERVER_ERROR,
                    AppConstants.RESPONSE_TEXT_ERROR, e.getMessage());
        }
        //This response shows success on debug in eclipse.
        return response;
    }
```

> Exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`questapp`.`cs_partner_discount`, CONSTRAINT `FK_dis_place` FOREIGN KEY (`place_id`) REFERENCES `cs_place` (`place_id`))
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar:5.1.45]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3325) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3562) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:599) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
and so on.
```

Comment: You need to catch your exception or you need an answer for your exception?

Comment: I need to catch the exception. I know what cause the exception but dont know how to catch exception